# How to pass array of integers to the stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jasper-reports

I have a procedure in PostgreSQL:

```
select * from sp_report_projectwise_userwise_sales2(integer, integer, integer, integer, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, integer[])
```

and i created report in *Jaspersoft Studio*. I'm calling the above query to generate report but I cant create the array parameter (for that integer) in Studio.

How to declare array paramter in JasperReports?

I tried `java.lang.Integer[]` but no use getting error. How to solve this?

Comment: Same issue for SQL Server. You can pass it to a query but not a stored procedure. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: No, I never tried in SQL server

Comment: I know you are looking for an answer 4 years later lol. For SQL Server, we are passing in a list of integers as a string (comma separated list). That was the recommendation from Jaspersoft. That or modify the Jaspersoft source code

Answer (score 0):

When you create a parameter from scratch the program will prompt you for the name and the Class and there you can write *java.lang.Integer[]* or *java.util.List* I think either one can do the job you need.

[image: Parameter name and type]